# Finding a cubic formula for roots of cubic equations

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, factoring, cubics

Solve for $x$,
$$27x^3+21x+8=0$$

I would like to know if there exists an formula for cubic equations just like quadratic formula for quadratic equations.

Comment: [Cardano's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_equation#Cardano's_formula) works, but it is not exactly easy to use.  Your example has a rational root, so it is best to start there.

Comment: Not clear what you want by way of more details, Robert. Could you be more explicit about what is missing in the answers that have been posted?

Comment: Please, Robert, what more do you need?

Comment: Sorry for delay in replying

Comment: I am actually looking for a method which can be always applied (as the quadratic formula)to solve a cubic almost instantaneously

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can begin by making an general cubic equation into a depressed cubic( missing square term)

To make $$ax^3+bx^2+cx+d=0$$ a depressed cubic we substitute $$x=y-\frac b{3a}$$  to get
$$a {\left[y-\frac b{3a}\right]}^3+b{\left[y-\frac b{3a}\right]}^2+c{\left[y-\frac b{3a}\right]}+d=0$$

Which simplyfies to $$ay^3+y \left[c-\frac b{3a}\right]+\left[d+\frac{2b^3}{27a^2}-\frac{bc}{3a}\right]=0$$

Now we have a depressed cubic so now we can just simply use the shortened Cardano's formula which is,
$$ x={\left[\frac{-d}2+\sqrt{\frac{d^2}4+ \frac{c^3}{27}}\right]}^\frac13 +{\left[\frac{-d}2-\sqrt{\frac{d^2}4+ \frac{c^3}{27}}\right]}^\frac13 $$

Just put up the values and answer will pop out!

Answer (score 8):

Better way to do it is this. If you write $t=3x$ you get $$t^3+7t+8=0$$

so $$t^3+1+7t+7=0$$ $$(t+1)(t^2-t+1)+7(t+1)=0$$

Now it is easy to finish.

Answer (score 3):

Yes it exists. It's called Cardano's Method of Solving Cubics of the form of cubic you posted. 
This form is called a depressed cubic because it has the $x^2$ term missing.

You can read in detail about it [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_equation#Cardano's_formula)

But it is not required in your case. You can run the rational roots test and find out that one of the roots can be easily found.